# JQuery append td to specific th

Tags: jquery, html, datatable, append

I am have a `table` with several `th` elements, each one having a unique value.

I want to append a `td` matching the `td` value with `th` value and append it under the same order.

I tried this code but it appends the data within the same `th`! I want the `td` in new line of `tr`.

```
  $("<td>" + data[i][0].counter + "</td>").insertAfter("#datatable th[value='"+data[i][d].orderStatus+"']").trigger("create");
```

Comment: Can I assume `data[i][0].counter` is the unique value?

Comment: Also a minimal snippet of the html of your table would make this question better.

Comment: am using jade , below my code for unique tr

table#datatable.table.table-striped.table-bordered.table-hover
    thead
        tr
            th Date
            -for(var i in status) {
            th(value=i)=status[i]
            -}
    tbody

Comment: @Faisal That's `jade` which isn't one of your tags. Your table exists in DOM? If so, what does it have? A `<thead>` with `<th>` only? is there a `<tbody>`? You must have some sort of HTML, correct? When you say you want to append a `<td>` do you mean the ***data*** of a `<td>` or a real `<td>`?

Answer (score 2):

```
$("<td>" + data[i][0].counter + "</td>")
                     .insertAfter("#datatable th[value='"+data[i][d].orderStatus+"']")
                     .trigger("create");
```

I am assuming that all of this is occuring in a loop and with that assumption, this is what I will work off of. So first, I will step through your code starting from the beginning to help you understand some things.

> $("" + data[i][0].counter + "")

As you *may* or *may not* be aware, `$("x")` in jquery is the equivalent of using a CSS selector. For instance, if I wanted to set all `<div>` elements that have a class of `.example-div` to have a black background with jquery - I could do so with the following:

```
<div class="example-div">Hello, World!</div>

<script>
    $('.example-div').css({"background-color":"#000000"});
    /* OR if I wanted to set all divs to have a black background. */
    $('div').css({"background-color":"#000000"});
</script>
```

Placing physical tags with `<>` in the selector will most likely cause problems. First, you must select the element(*s*) that you wish to interact with. In your case, the following may work depending on your need.

```
$("#datatable th[value='"+data[i][d].orderStatus+"']")
```

Also, look at the change I made to the selector. I removed the `>` after `#datatable`. The greater than character (`>`) selects immediate children and `<th>` is not a child of `<table id="datatable">`. It is a child of `<tr>` which is then a child of `<thead>` as shown in this example: (`<table><thead><tr><th>`) An instance where this would work is in the following:

`$("#datatable > thead > tr > th")`

Now for the next part of your code:

> InsertAfter("#datatable th[value='"+data[i][d].orderStatus+"']")

I understand by looking at this what you meant when you wrote it. You want the insert `"<td>" + data[i][0].counter + "<td>"` after the `<th>` tag that contains the value `data[i][d].orderStatus`. You've effectively got these reversed because you're trying to insert the selector after the html. Here's what *should* work:

```
$("#datatable th[value='"+data[i][d].orderStatus+"']").after("<td>" + data[i][0].counter + "</td>");
```

Note: Note that I am using `after` instead of `insertAfter`, this is irrelevant.

> The .after() and .insertAfter() methods perform the same task.
>   [(After & InsertAfter)][1] [1]: http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/

I am not sure what event you're trying to trigger with `create` but you can also chain this at the end if it's still necessary.

```
$("#datatable th[value='"+data[i][d].orderStatus+"']").after("<td>" + data[i][0].counter + "</td>").trigger("create");
```

Comment: Thank you so much, sir , I think my idea it not clear, am having a table with dates and order status, I want to append the data to the table and coordinate the data with each row (order status) 

so before appending the data , i wanna insert the data with specific position of rows and column, how can i tell jquery to search to the row and column and insert it as a child ??

i tried your code and it's inserted the data but in <th> ?? because I selected the the <th> itself not the child of it

Comment: i have opened a new question to make everything clear , plz check it 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44039352/jquery-insert-cell-to-specific-position-of-tr-value-and-td-value