# JQuery insert cell to specific position of tr value and td value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, pug

I am having a table contain the following structure:

[image]

The status in thead having value with unique number,
and the date also having a unique value of the date itself.

What I want is to add cell after matching the (cell status and cell date),

so , I am having the following JSON:

```
{
  "data": [
    [
      {
        "orderStatus": 2,
        "date_formatted": "15-05-2017",
        "counter": 2
      },
      {
        "orderStatus": 4,
        "date_formatted": "15-05-2017",
        "counter": 14
      },
      {
        "orderStatus": 5,
        "date_formatted": "15-05-2017",
        "counter": 12
      },
      {
        "orderStatus": 11,
        "date_formatted": "15-05-2017",
        "counter": 6
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "orderStatus": 2,
        "date_formatted": "16-05-2017",
        "counter": 6
      },
      {
        "orderStatus": 4,
        "date_formatted": "16-05-2017",
        "counter": 15
      },
      {
        "orderStatus": 5,
        "date_formatted": "16-05-2017",
        "counter": 12
      },
      {
        "orderStatus": 11,
        "date_formatted": "16-05-2017",
        "counter": 5
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "orderStatus": 2,
        "date_formatted": "17-05-2017",
        "counter": 4
      },
      {
        "orderStatus": 4,
        "date_formatted": "17-05-2017",
        "counter": 10
      },
      {
        "orderStatus": 5,
        "date_formatted": "17-05-2017",
        "counter": 13
      },
      {
        "orderStatus": 11,
        "date_formatted": "17-05-2017",
        "counter": 6
      }
    ]
  ],
  "status_name": {
    "1": "New",
    "2": "Pending",
    "3": "On Way",
    "4": "Completed",
    "5": "Cancelled Client",
    "6": "Time out",
    "7": "Secluded",
    "8": "On Progress",
    "9": "Receipt created",
    "10": "Provider Arrive",
    "11": "Provider cancelled",
    "12": "Provider start the work",
    "13": "Provider paused the work",
    "14": "No Provider Available"
  }
}
```

So I want to enter the order status under two specific data (match the thead th order status + match the json element with tbody td date).

I tried this jquery code and it's not working:

```
$("table thead:tr:th[value='2'] tbody:tr:td:[value='2017-20-9']").after(data["data"][count]["counter"]);
```

and this is my sample code in a snippet:

```js
$("table thead:tr:th[value='2'] tbody:tr:td:[value='2017-20-9']").after("<td>Test</td>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
            <th value='2'> Completed </th>
            <th value='4'> Cancelled </th>
            <th value='5'> Pending </th>
            <th value='1'> Arrived </th>
            <th value='9'> Waiting </th>
            <th value='10'> Cancelled Provider</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td value='2017-20-8'>2017-20-8</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td value='2017-20-9'>2017-20-9</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `<td>` does not have a `value` attribute only form controls do like `<input>`, `<output>`, etc. Why is the content of the headers dynamic? The table's headers are usually static and the cells are dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructs like this `thead:tr:th` are invalid css selectors, you need to use something like this instead `thead tr th`.

To achieve what you want you can do this:

```js
$(function(){
  // Determine the horizontal position
  var headerIndex = $("table thead tr th[value=9]").index();
  // Determine the vertical position
  var columnIndex = $("tbody tr:has(td[value=2017-20-9])").index();
  
  // Fill the row with cells to set the horizontal position appropriately
  while($("tbody tr").eq(columnIndex).find("td").length < headerIndex){
    $("tbody tr").eq(columnIndex).append("<td></td>");
  }
  
  // Check if there is already a cell at the given index and if it is, change its text otherwise add a new cell.
  if($("tbody tr").eq(columnIndex).find("td").eq(headerIndex).length){
    $("tbody tr").eq(columnIndex).find("td").eq(headerIndex).text("Inserted");
  }else{
    $("tbody tr").eq(columnIndex).append("<td>Inserted</td>");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
            <th> Date </th>
            <th value='2'> Completed </th>
            <th value='4'> Cancelled </th>
            <th value='5'> Pending </th>
            <th value='1'> Arrived </th>
            <th value='9'> Waiting </th>
            <th value='10'> Cancelled Provider</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td value='2017-20-8'>2017-20-8</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td value='2017-20-9'>2017-20-9</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I've added some comments to explain what the code does.

The basic idea is to determine the header's position (its index) and the column's position.

You can't just add a column to a row at a given horizontal position, you'll have to fill the row with cells up to that position in order to arrange the cell horizontally.

Comment: thank you so much sir, and I think this is the correct answer, but is there an easier way to do that without looping !! already I have 3 loops and with this on3 it will be 4 loops !!! to much for one page

Comment: @Faisal If the rows have the same number of cells (one cell for each header) you don't need that loop. In any case, 4 loops are not that many, I think the time required to run this loop is negligible (only a couple of milliseconds).

Comment: so if am sure that each cell having another cell in header , no need to do the looping !??, what about the order ! should i make them same order?

can u please write the code again without loop , that will be great 

many thnx and ur answer is the correct one

Comment: @Faisal Actually, the code doesn't need any modifications. If the row has all the required cells for the new cell to be added at the correct position, the loop won't have any iterations (won't run). Try to understand what the code does, is not that complex. After that, you will be able to modify it yourself to better suit your needs.